# regex private ips and remove from logfile

Tags: sed, regular-expression

i have a large AWS ELB logfile from which i want to remove the private ip, for example:

```
2018-06-03T23:59:57.000Z 66.249.66.129,10.0.1.81 [03/Jun/2018:23:59:57 +0000] "GET http://www.domain0.com/latest-news/dubai-duty-free-sales-rise-11-q1-12-04-2018/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16669 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
2018-06-03T23:59:58.000Z 82.113.167.2,10.0.1.132 [03/Jun/2018:23:59:58 +0000] "GET http://www.domain3.com/feed HTTP/1.1" 200 17144 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11"
2018-06-03T23:59:58.000Z 192.243.55.95,10.0.1.81 [03/Jun/2018:23:59:58 +0000] "GET http://www.domain1.com/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18532 "https://www.domain1.com/feed" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.0~bm; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
2018-06-03T23:59:58.000Z 207.46.13.236,10.0.1.81 [03/Jun/2018:23:59:58 +0000] "GET http://www.domain.com/blogs/gadget-master/general/brightsparks-trophies-make-mark-2017-05/https/blogs/distribution-world/page/9/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
2018-06-03T23:59:59.000Z 62.210.215.100,10.0.1.81 [03/Jun/2018:23:59:59 +0000] "GET http://www.domain.com/electro-ramblings/tag/blog/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1664 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.66 Safari/537.36"`, "\n")
```

gets me the regex

but when i run it

```
cat logs.txt | sed '/T/s/T/:/1' | sed -E 's/,10.0/ /g'
```

but this only returns

```
2018-06-03:23:59:57.000Z 66.249.66.129 .1.81 
...
```

how do i remove the private ip with the `,` from the file using regex in sed?

any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the requirement was to remove "private" IPs (10...) only, the regex given by ender.qa could be refined to

```
sed -E '/T/s/T/:/1; s/,10\.([0-9]{1,3}.){2}[0-9]{1,3}//g' file
```

or, as that IP would not contain spaces, even shorter:

```
sed -E '/T/s/T/:/1; s/,10\.[^ ]*//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want your 'data before':

`2018-06-03T23:59:57.000Z 66.249.66.129,10.0.1.81 [03/Jun/2018:23:59:57 +0000] ...`

to be 'data after':

`2018-06-03:23:59:57.000Z 66.249.66.129 [03/Jun/2018:23:59:57 +0000] ...`

Is that correct?

If yes:

`cat logs.txt | sed '/T/s/T/:/1' | sed -e 's/,.*\[//g'`

Also, you don't need the `cat`:

`sed '/T/s/T/:/1' logs.txt | sed -e 's/,.*\[/ \[/g'`

Basically, you are removing any characters (.*) between the comma (,) and the left bracket ([), which needs to be escaped.

If you only want to remove the IP address

`sed '/T/s/T/:/1' logs.txt | sed -re 's/,([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}//g'`

OR

`sed '/T/s/T/:/1' logs.txt | sed -e 's/,\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}//g'`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928879/4635198

Answer (score 0):

Not *quite* what you asked for, but this shows [how to use `grepcidr`](http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/) to filter out (remove) *lines* containing IP addresses in the private address range 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255 in the file `file`:

```
grepcidr -v '10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255' file
```

The same thing, but using CIDR network block syntax:

```
grepcidr -v '10.0.0.0/8' file
```